# Python: Urllib2 check for missing content-length in header

Tags: python, urllib2, content-length

I have a script which "appeared" to work in our test environment, as there was lack of visibility. However we are now testing in our pre-prod environment we have noticed the following issue...

The basic function of the script is to perform HTTP/URL requests on the host web front end and return the status code and also the content size (i.e. `content-length`). I am having trouble working out, how to do a check for the `content-lenght` before assigning it to a variable. At the moment I have the following:

```
#... Code ...
try:
  conn = urllib2.urlopen(line, timeout=1)
  contentLen = conn.headers['content-length']
#... Code ...
```

However for URLs that lack this content-length it simply breaks the script if content length is missing. Rather than raising an exception I would like to simply check for it's existance before assigning `contentLen` and then if it exists assign the actual `content-length` value, if it doesn't exist then assign the value "NULL". So this can then be printed as "`Null`".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn.headers` is a `httplib.HTTPMessage`, which is a subclass of `rfc822.Message` and thus has a (limited) [`dict`-like interface](http://docs.python.org/2/library/rfc822.html#rfc822.Message.get). You can use the 2-argument call to `get` to supply a default value.

```
contentLen = conn.headers.get('content-length','NULL')
```